# Dirac equation and particle probability density

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, dirac-equation

I do know that nowadays dirac equation is interpreted as field-theoretic equation, not as particle equation.

But is there any sense that dirac equation can still be said to have wavefunction that gives us probability density of a particle at some location that can be verified with some form of experiment?

I do know that in real-life experiment, we verify QFT theories by scattering experiments, with transition probability checked using S-matrix. So the question is about whether probability density in location basis can still have experimental/observational meaning in dirac equatio, and not just historical coincidence of Dirac trying to derive positive-definite probability density for a particle in relativistic setting.

Comment: See answer to this related question, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/193506/what-is-phix0-rangle/193518#193518 and especially the link therein, http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~neum/physfaq/topics/position.html

Comment: Dirac equation should be interpreted as the equation of motion of the classical Dirac field. It is not the Schroedinger equation in quantum physics.

There is a book "The Dirac Equation" by Bernd Thaller talking about the details of the interpretations of Dirac equation.